# construct cell array of ordered pairs from matrices

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array, cell

I want to create a cell array of ordered pairs from the following two matrices...

i.e.

```
[X,Y] = meshgrid(1:10,1:10)
```

X =

```
 1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10
 1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10
 1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10
 1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10
 1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10
 1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10
 1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10
 1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10
 1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10
 1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10
```

Y =

```
 1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
 2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2
 3     3     3     3     3     3     3     3     3     3
 4     4     4     4     4     4     4     4     4     4
 5     5     5     5     5     5     5     5     5     5
 6     6     6     6     6     6     6     6     6     6
 7     7     7     7     7     7     7     7     7     7
 8     8     8     8     8     8     8     8     8     8
 9     9     9     9     9     9     9     9     9     9
10    10    10    10    10    10    10    10    10    10
```

...where the (what I assume to be 1x2x10x10) cell array Z is a cell array where all of the entries in X and Y are x and y coordinates, with each individual pair of coordinates being an element of Z:

```
Z = { (1,1)  (2,1)  (3,1)  ... (10,1);
  (1,2)  (2,2)  (3,2)  ... (10,2);
  ...     ...    ...   ...  ...;
  (1,10) (2,10) (3,10) ... (10,10) }
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: The size description confused me a bit. I believe you are actually looking for a 10x10 cell array of 1x2 vectors.

Comment: Note that if your actual solution involves filling a cell array with numbers from 1:n, there is probably an easier way to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Z = squeeze(num2cell(permute(cat(3,X,Y),[3,1,2]),1));
```

Steps:

1. Concatenate X and Y along the third dimension:

   ```
   Z = cat(3,X,Y)
   ```
2. Permute the resulting array to have coordinate pairs along first dimension:

   ```
   Z = permute(Z,[3,1,2])
   ```
3. Convert to cell array:

   ```
   Z = num2cell(Z)
   ```
4. Remove unnecessary singleton dimensions from cell array:

   ```
   Z = squeeze(Z)
   ```

The resulting cell array contains the coordinate pairs as 2x1 column vectors on the form

```
[x-coordinate; y-coordinate]
```

Answer (score 1):

What would be wrong with

```
Z = cat(3, X,Y)
```

so that

```
>> Z(1, 2, :)
ans(:,:,1) =
     2
ans(:,:,2) =
     1
```

If you don't like the 1-by-1-by-2 format, you could do this

```
Z = cellfun(@squeeze, num2cell(cat(3,X,Y),3), 'UniformOutput', false)
```

Or this

```
Z = reshape(num2cell([X(:) Y(:)], 2), size(X))
```

Answer (score 0):

What I would probably use myself is something different, like:

```
[X(:) Y(:)]
```

However, my attempt to give you the output you are looking for in the simplest way would be:

```
Z=num2cell(cat(3,X,Y),3)
```